# How to use group_by and summerise functions together with a condition?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has three columns "time" and "status" and "water_level". Time variable has a format like "2007-03-22 06:45:00" and spans many years. status is a binary variable with only two values of "High" or "Low" (You can think of a sensor that has measured something for many years day by day and minute by minute and decided if the measurement is Low or High).

```
 time   status   water_level 
2007-03-21 06:20:00 Low  2.4 
2007-03-21 19:55:00 Low  2.3 
2007-03-21 23:50:00 High 2.1 
2016-04-10 19:55:00 Low  3.5 
2016-04-11 23:50:00 High 3.6
```

---

My goal is to calculate the average of water_level within each month only if the number of "High" and "Low" for that month is equal otherwise I want that month to be removed completely.

I tried group_by and summerise functions together but couldn't incorporate the condition and have no idea how to do it. So I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
          group_by(time = floor_date(time, "month")) %>%
                 if(length(status == 'High') == length(status == 'Low')
                 {summarize(water_level = mean(water_level)}
                   else {summarize(water_level = 'NA'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(month= months(time)) %>% 
  add_count(month, status) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
   filter(length(unique(n)) == 1) %>% 
   summarise(mean_water_level = mean(water_level, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  month mean_water_level
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 April             3.55
```

If there are months with only one stutus include this term in the filter 
`& length(unique(status)) == 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using similar approach as your original attempt but using the `filter` function instead of the `if` statement.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydata %>% 
    group_by(time = format(time, "%Y-%m")) %>% 
      filter(sum(status == 'High') == sum(status == 'Low')) %>%
         summarize(water_level = mean(water_level))
```

Also note the use of `sum` instead of `length`.  `length(status == 'High')` will return the length of status since it will count all of the TRUE and FALSE.  `sum` will only count the TRUE.